# What does Request.text() (and other functions implemented from Body) actually do?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Based on [its MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request), `Request` has implemented functions from `Body`, like `text()`. However, I have no idea what these functions actually do. They don't seem to do anything.

I have a code like this

```js
var r = new Request('http://google.com');
r.text().then(function(text) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(text));
}, function(error) {
    alert("error");
});
```

What happens is that the promise immediately resolves, with an empty string, and no request happens - if you look at Network activity in dev tools (or wireshark), no actual request happens. But there is also no error.

What is going on? What is the purpose of the `Body` API?

<del>The description on MDN talk about "Response stream" but there is no Response (since there was no actual fetch yet).</del> (edit: Since I answered my own question, I also edited the MDN page so it makes sense now.)

[The specs](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) state the following:

> A Request object's consume body algorithm, given a type, runs these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If this Request object is disturbed, return a new promise rejected
>      with a TypeError.
> 2. Set disturbed flag.
> 3. Let p be a new promise.
> 4. Run these substeps in parallel:
>
>    1. Let bytes be the empty byte sequence.
>    2. If request's body is not null, set bytes to the result of reading from
>         request's body until it returns end-of-stream.
>    3. Resolve p with the result of running the package data algorithm with
>         bytes, type and MIME type. If that threw an exception, reject p with
>         that exception.
> 5. Return p.

I am not very smart from that.

(Note: I know that what I am asking is a very detailed question. I am not asking about what `fetch`/`Response`/`Request` does in general.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can actually add some body to the request and the `.text()` etc. will return the *body of the request*.

An easy example:

```js
// method cannot be GET for custom body
var r = new Request('http://google.com', {method: 'POST', body: "something"}); 
r.text().then(function(text) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(text)); // alerts "something"
}, function(error) {
    alert("error");
});
```

and that's basically it. The example in the question had no body, so it resolves with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation:

> A Request object's consume body algorithm, given a type, runs these
>   steps:
>
> 1. If this Request object is disturbed, return a new promise rejected
>      with a TypeError.
> 2. Set disturbed flag.
> 3. Let p be a new promise.
> 4. Run these substeps in parallel:
>
>    1. Let bytes be the empty byte sequence.
>    2. If request's body is not null, set bytes to the result of reading from
>         request's body until it returns end-of-stream.
>    3. Resolve p with the result of running the package data algorithm with
>         bytes, type and MIME type. If that threw an exception, reject p with
>         that exception.
> 5. Return p.

Follow 1, 2, 3, 4.1, 4.2 is false, 4.3 brings you to the package data algorithm (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-package-data), which, for `text`, returns the result of running utf-8 decode on `bytes`.

`bytes` is an empty byte sequence, so the promise is resolved to the empty string.

Comment: Hm. What is it for exactly? Oh I see, you can actually set the body yourself in the constructor for... some reason. That's weird and seems quite useless.

Comment: OH I AM STUPID, it's actually *the body of the request*! So if you add a picture etc, it will read *the request body*! OK I got it now.

Comment: I have added my own answer below (cannot accept it now, in 2 days).

Comment: I'm not sure why you unaccepted my answer and accepted yours.

Comment: sorry for late reply. My problem was that I just misunderstood what the "body" in all the documentation refers to, which I better illustrated - to myself - by my code example.